# Returning new Object from Service that uses $resource

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am working on making my existing code a bit better and I would like to have two objects for interacting with a RESTful API.

Previously, I used $http to get get the data and return the promise. I would then .then some actions to it. Then I would requery to get additional data and repeat it. So there were several nested $http queries. I would like to avoid that if possible.

I would like to have a service (or a factory) that I can use to configure various query parameters and another object for massaging and outputting the response.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var solr1 = angular.module('solr', ['ngResource']);

solr1.run(function(){
    console.log("Module Loaded");
});

solr1.service('solrser', function($resource,solrresult) {
    console.log("In Solrser")
    this.serverurl = 'url';
    this.res = $resource(this.serverurl);

    this.query = function (p) {
        this.res.get(p).$promise.then(function(d) {
         return solrresult(d);
     });
    }
});

solr1.factory('solrresult',function() {
 return function(a) {
  this.data = a;
  this.ready = 0;

  console.log("In Factory")

  this.getdocs = function() {
   console.log("Getting Data")
   console.log(this.data);
   return this.data.docs;   //this is line 9
  }

  return this;
 }});
```

Controller looks like this:

```
app.controller('app1cont', ['$scope', 'solrser', 'solrresult', function($scope,solrser,solrresult){
    console.log("Start");
    var res = solrser.query({'q':'potato'});
    console.log(res)
    console.log(res.getdocs())
}]);
```

The output looks like this:

```
Module Loaded solr_module.js:5
In Solrser solr_module.js:9
Start main_controller.js:6
undefined main_controller.js:9
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getdocs' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (.........../main_controller.js:10:21)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.min.js:36:365)
    at F.instance (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.min.js:75:91)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.min.js:58:287
    at s (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.min.js:7:408)
    at G (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.min.js:58:270)
    at g (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.min.js:51:172)
    at g (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.min.js:51:189)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.min.js:50:280
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.min.js:18:8 angular.js:11339
In Factory solr_module.js:25
```

So the factory gets created after the controller resumes execution. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a timing issue.

```
app.controller('app1cont', ['$scope', 'solrser', 'solrresult', function($scope,solrser,solrresult){
    console.log("Start");
    var res = solrser.query({'q':'potato'});
    console.log(res)
    console.log(res.getdocs())
}]);
```

When you call `solrser.query()` it runs *async* to get the data. So the `res` is not populated with any real value until after the promise returns inside the `"solrser"` service. You would need to do something more like:

```
solrser.query({'q':'potato'},function(res) {
    console.log(res); 
    console.log(res.getdocs()); 
});  // could be done as a promise as well....
```

Separately, you also are doing something really strange when the response is called inside the `solrser` service.

```
    this.query = function (p) {
    this.res.get(p).$promise.then(function(d) {
     return solrresult(d);
 });
}
```

Calling `return` from within the promise handler is not going to do you very much. You need to either call a callback or resolve a deferred. Something like this would work better:

```
    this.query = function (p,callback) {
    this.res.get(p).$promise.then(function(d) {
     callback(solrresult(d));
 });
}
```

Or as a promise

```
this.query = function (p) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    this.res.get(p).$promise.then(function(d) {
     defer.resolve(solrresult(d));
 });
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Or you could just pass the `get(p).$promise` through, etc.

UPDATE:

Since this is an async action, there will always be a promise or callback. You have to do one of:

```
    app.controller('app1cont', ['$scope', 'solrser', 'solrresult', function($scope,solrser,solrresult){
    var res = solrser.query({'q':'potato'},function() {
        res.getDocs();
    });
}]);
```

Or just straight callback

```
    app.controller('app1cont', ['$scope', 'solrser', 'solrresult', function($scope,solrser,solrresult){
    solrser.query({'q':'potato'},function(res) {
        res.getDocs();
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I know it's a timing issue. I am trying to run through all async actions within this module so that within the controller I can just focus on the data. Basically, what I want in the end is to just get the data into the controller when it is finished. Not a promise that I still have to do stuff too, but the actual data. How can that be done?

Comment: Since the actions are async, there will always be some kind of callback. I will edit above.

Comment: How can I prevent the function returning until the data is present? In this case, there is really nothing to do until the data gets to the user, so there is no point in async actions.And the thing is that the data is not ready for presentation as soon as I get it, I have to massage it a bit and run some more $http calls.

Comment: You cannot. That is the thing about async. It is all callbacks or promises. I mean, yes, I could probably contrive something, but it would be very difficult. Not worth the headache

Comment: Ok, maybe I am not thinking about it the right away. If I use this as intended, I would have multiple nested statements in my controller that look like $http.get(a).then -> $http.get(somethinglese).then -> $http.get(more data).then. they are all nested and I really don't like that for some reason. IS there a better way?

Comment: Why wouldn't you wrap all of these statements inside a service, and then you have a single `MyService.get(params).then()` or `MyService.get(params,function(res){})` ? Isn't that what you were trying to do?

Comment: Wouldn't I just have the same problem in the service then? Sorry, I am just starting with JS/Angular and async programming is not easy for me to wrap my head around.

Comment: If I had to make something like this in perl or python I would have an object for querying the system and another object for parsing out different types of results (since output varies). I am trying to replicate this in angular/js so I can abstract all the guts and modularize it for reuse.

Comment: Yes, you would, but it is easier to deal with in a service. This kind of complex structuring is what a service is about, so your controllers are thin and light. And if you are doing multiple queries in async that you need to manage, think about caolan's awesome async lib https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 0):

I see missing semicolon

```
console.log("In Solrser")
```

shouldbe

```
console.log("In Solrser");
```

also missing semicolon here

```
console.log("Getting Data")
console.log("In Factory")
```

in controller you have missing semicolons too.
I think this is a reason why your code don't work.

To avoid bug like missing semicolon you can use JSHint plugin in your IDE

Comment: I fixed the semicolons and still running into the same issue. Please review the output in console I provided. Clearly the factory is starting too late.